# Convert Name of columns(years) to variable values - Python, R

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a CSV which looks like these:

```
                       1991       1992      1993       1991       1992      1993
VariableA  VariableB   VariableC  VariableC VariableC  VariableD  VariableD VariableD
     lm          mt         1          3          4            2        3         5
```

So I would like to create a variable called year and do the following:

```
VariableA VariableB     Year   VariableC   VariableD 
 lm          mt         1991      1            2
 lm          mt         1992      3            3
 lm          mt         1993      4            5
```

I mostly work with Pandas which I'm learning but I don't know to read properly that data and then do the manipulation. If someone comes up with a solution in R, it would be nice too.

**EDITION :**

My real data frame are with years from 1991 to 2013 and there are more variables that has duplicates. I tried the code inr R with the package `splitstackshape` suggested by [Ananda Mahto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270695/ananda-mahto) , but I get an error message. So, what's my error?

```
mydf <- read.csv("DatosCOMPUSTATfinal.csv", skip = 3, check.names = FALSE)

nombres <- names(mydf)[-c(1,2,3)]

nombres <- unique(nombres)

> nombres
 [1] "Employees"                  "Market Value-daily"        
 [3] "Market to book - daily"     "Total return"              
 [5] "Total assets"               "total stockholders' equity"
 [7] "Sales"                      "EBITDA"                    
 [9] "EBIT"                       "Pretax income"             
[11] "Income (loss)"             

> names(mydf[c(1,2,3)])
    [1] "Company name"            "employer identification"
    [3] "CUSIP"     

names(mydf)[-c(1,2,3)] <- paste(names(mydf)[-c(1,2,3)], 
                               c(1991:2013), sep = "_")


nv <- merged.stack(mydf, id.vars = names(mydf[c(1,2,3)]) , var.stubs = nombres , sep = "_" )
```

Then, I get the error message:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 1L) { : argument is of length zero
```

**EDITION 2:**

I tried this code with the reshape function, but I receive the message "memory exhausted". I don't know why because the data frame is just changing its direction and its size is less than 15 mb. Why that happens and How can I deal with that?

```
newmydf <- reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = 1:3, varying = 4:ncol(mydf), sep = "_")
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
```

Comment: Do you actually have a `csv` file, separated by commas, or is the data exactly as you have posted, simply separated by spaces?

Comment: I have a CSV with the same structure. The years are actually from 1991 to 2013.

Comment: So, to clarify, there are 11*23 (253) columns in "mydf"? Let me see if I can recreate the error.

Comment: 253 in var.stubs plus 3 in id.vars, 256 in total.

Answer (score 7):

In R, one way might be to read the csv skipping the first line, adding that back in as a part of your variable names, and then using `reshape` to get the output you want.

Try something like the following:

```
mydf <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", skip = 1, check.names = FALSE)
names(mydf)[-c(1, 2)] <- paste(names(mydf)[-c(1, 2)], 
                               c(1991, 1992, 1993), sep = "_")
reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar = 1:2, 
        varying = 3:ncol(mydf), sep = "_")
#            VariableA VariableB time VariableC VariableD
# lm.mt.1991        lm        mt 1991         1         2
# lm.mt.1992        lm        mt 1992         3         3
# lm.mt.1993        lm        mt 1993         4         5
```

---

After the renaming step, if `reshape()` is too slow for you, try `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("VariableC", "VariableD"), sep = "_")
#    VariableA VariableB .time_1 VariableC VariableD
# 1:        lm        mt    1991         1         2
# 2:        lm        mt    1992         3         3
# 3:        lm        mt    1993         4         5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way in `R` is to use `dplyr/tidyr` (which would be faster for big datasets) after you read the dataset using `read.csv` as mentioned in @Ananda Mahto's post

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

  mydf %>% 
       gather(Var, Val, matches("[0-9]+$")) %>% 
       separate(Var, c("Var", "Year")) %>%
       spread(Var, Val)

  #  VariableA VariableB Year VariableC VariableD
  #1        lm        mt 1991         1         2
  #2        lm        mt 1992         3         3
  #3        lm        mt 1993         4         5
```

#### data

```
 mydf <- structure(list(VariableA = structure(1L, .Label = "lm", class = "factor"), 
VariableB = structure(1L, .Label = "mt", class = "factor"), 
VariableC_1991 = 1L, VariableC_1992 = 3L, VariableC_1993 = 4L, 
VariableD_1991 = 2L, VariableD_1992 = 3L, VariableD_1993 = 5L), .Names = c("VariableA", 
"VariableB", "VariableC_1991", "VariableC_1992", "VariableC_1993", 
"VariableD_1991", "VariableD_1992", "VariableD_1993"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: I might be biased, but I prefer `merged.stack` here :-)